# Цвет пункта меню

Tags: jquery, функции, методы

Здравствуйте, мне надо, чтобы я смог повесить на секцию `id="active"` и при скроллинге на эту секцию нужный мне пункт меню менял цвет с черного на зеленый. То есть нужен скрипт который будет определять когда я на секции с `id="active"` и будет менять цвет одного пункта меню. Проще говоря это что-то на подобии зависимости:

1 секция - меняет цвет 1 пункт меню;

2 секция - меняет цвет 2 пункт меню;

3 секция - меняет цвет 3 пункт меню.

Заранее благодарю

Comment: а вы пробовали самому что то сделать ? или хотите сразу получить готовый ответ ?

Answer (score 2):

Вариантов много, вот один из них:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('scroll', onScroll);

  // Плавная анимация
  $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(document).off('scroll');

    $('a').each(function() {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    });
    $(this).addClass('active');

    var target = this.hash,
      $target = $(target);

    $('html, body').stop().animate({
      'scrollTop': $target.offset().top + 2
    }, 500, 'swing', function() {
      window.location.hash = target;
      $(document).on('scroll', onScroll);
    });
  });
});

function onScroll() {
  var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop(),
    link = $('#menu').find('a');

  link.each(function() {
    var currLink = $(this),
      refElement = $(currLink.attr('href'));

    if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
      link.removeClass('active');
      currLink.addClass('active');
    }
  });
}
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
html {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 960px;
}

.menu {
  background-color: rgba(4, 180, 49, 0.6);
  position: fixed;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  width: 100%;
}

#menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#menu li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
}

#menu a {
  color: #000;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 75px;
  padding: 0 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#menu .active,
#menu a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  color: #fff;
}

section {
  padding: 100px 25px 25px;
}

#home {
  background-color: #286090;
  height: 100vh;
}

#portfolio {
  background: gray;
  height: 100vh;
}

#about {
  background-color: #07c;
  height: 100vh;
}

#contact {
  background-color: rgb(154, 45, 45);
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="menu">
  <div class="container">
    <ul id="menu">
      <li><a href="#home" class="active">Главная</a></li>
      <li><a href="#portfolio">Портфолио</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">О нас</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Контакт</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<section id="home">
  <div class="container">
    Главная
  </div>
</section>
<section id="portfolio">
  <div class="container">
    Портфолио
  </div>
</section>
<section id="about">
  <div class="container">
    О нас
  </div>
</section>
<section id="contact">
  <div class="container">
    Контакт
  </div>
</section>
```

Для bootstrap'а есть такое готовое решение:

https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-scrolling-nav

Comment: Спасибо что отписались, у вас хороший код, но не совсем то что нужно, я хотел чтобы пункты меню подсвечивались не только при их нажатии, а при самом скролле, то есть сделать зависимость от нахождения в секции и если я проскроллил до секции О нас, то соответственный пункт меню должен подсветится. Если поможете, буду нереально благодарен